How can I solve uncorrected relaxation trend for i-i collision from large scattering angles?
I'm facing with bugging problems of my collision code. My collision is trying to imply collision of charge particles by exchanging velocity through the subroutine collision inside the calculations module.The collision algorithm will calculate the relative velocity of two particle species and calculate other collisional parameters. Here, I inserted the corrected time step and Coulomb logarithm value due to collision frequency of proton-deuterium ion. The code will determine the scattering parameter "s", then determine the parameter "A", which leads to calculation of scattering angle, $\chi$. The conditions to compute $\chi$ followed the Nanbu algorithm. Then the velocity exchange will be computed by the velocity relationship with $\chi$. Here is my collision code. Finally I got the relxation so fast compare to theoretical trends. [relaxation_pD] (https://i.sstatic.net/e8OjTLgv.png)
module constants
    implicit none
    real(8), parameter :: m_e0 = 9.10938356e-31
    real(8), parameter :: mp = 1836.2*m_e0 ! Proton mass (kg)
    real(8), parameter :: md = 3670.5*m_e0 ! Deuterium Ion mass (kg)
    real(8), parameter :: Te = 70.0      ! Proton temperature (eV)
    real(8), parameter :: Ti = 50.0      ! Deuterium Ion temperature (eV)
    real(8), parameter :: ne = 1.0e18    ! Proton density (m^-3)
    real(8), parameter :: ni = 1.0e18    ! Deuterium Ion density (m^-3)
    real(8), parameter :: EC = 1.602176565E-19
    real(8), parameter :: ze = -1, zi = +1, qe = ze*EC, qi = zi*EC
    real(8), parameter :: az1 = 1, az2 = 1
    real(8), parameter :: pi = 3.141592653589793
    integer, parameter :: nt = 3000          ! iteration numbers
    integer, parameter :: np_cell = 100000    ! particle no. 
    real(8), parameter :: kb = 1.60218e-19     ! Boltzmann constant (J/eV)
    real(8), parameter :: epsilon0 = 8.854187817e-12
    real(8), parameter :: mass_re = mp*md/(mp+md)
    real(8), parameter :: logCou = 15.02    !log(lambda/b0av)
    real(8), parameter :: s01 = (logCou/(4*pi)), s02 = (qe*qi)/(epsilon0*mass_re)
    ! e-i coll freq
    real(8), parameter :: dt = 7.04e-4  ! Time step (s)
    real(8), parameter :: sabdt = s01*s02*s02*ni*dt
end module constants

module variables
    use constants
    implicit none
    real(8), allocatable :: vx_p(:), vy_p(:), vz_p(:)
    real(8), allocatable :: vx_d(:), vy_d(:), vz_d(:)
    real(8) :: t_p, t_d, vxp,vyp,vzp,vxd,vyd,vzd
    real(8) :: txp,typ,tzp,txd,tyd,tzd  
    integer :: iter, ia, ib, np
    real(8) :: r1, r2
end module variables

module calculations
    use constants
    use variables
    implicit none
contains

    subroutine alloc_dat
        np = np_cell
        allocate(vx_p(np), vy_p(np), vz_p(np))
        allocate(vx_d(np), vy_d(np), vz_d(np))
    end subroutine

    subroutine dealloc_dat
        deallocate(vx_p,vy_p,vz_p,vx_d,vy_d,vz_d)
    end subroutine

    ! initial Maxwellian distribution function of particle
    subroutine initialize_maxwellian(vx, vy, vz, T, m, n)
        implicit none
        real(8), intent(out) :: vx(n), vy(n), vz(n)
        real(8), intent(in) :: T, m
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(8) :: sigma, u1, u2, u3
        integer :: i

        sigma = sqrt(EC * T / m)

        !$omp parallel do private(i, u1, u2)
        do i = 1, n
            call random_number(u1)
            call random_number(u2)
            vx(i) = sigma * sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * cos(2.0 * pi * u2)*(sqrt(0.9/3.))
            call random_number(u1)
            call random_number(u2)
            vy(i) = sigma * sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * sin(2.0 * pi * u2)*(sqrt(1.5/3.))
            call random_number(u1)
            call random_number(u2)
            vz(i) = sigma * sqrt(-2.0 * log(u1)) * cos(2.0 * pi * u2)*(sqrt(0.6/3.))
        end do
        !$omp end parallel do
    end subroutine initialize_maxwellian


    ! Perform collsion between two species here
    subroutine collision(ia, ib)
        use, INTRINSIC :: ieee_arithmetic, ONLY: ieee_is_nan
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: ia, ib

        ! Local variables
        real(8) :: gx, gy, gz, g, gper, ivg3, sab, aa, dda, cospsi, sinpsi, beta
        real(8) :: cosbt, sinbt, hx, hy, hz, maab, mbab
        real(8) :: temp_e, temp_i
        real(8), parameter :: twopi = 6.28318530717958
        real(8) :: r1_local, r2_local

        ! Generate random numbers
        call random_number(r1_local)
        call random_number(r2_local)

        gx = vx_p(ia) - vx_d(ib)
        gy = vy_p(ia) - vy_d(ib)
        gz = vz_p(ia) - vz_d(ib)
        g = sqrt(gx**2 + gy**2 + gz**2)
        gper = sqrt(gy**2 + gz**2)
        if (gper == 0.0) then
            ! Avoid division by zero
            return
        end if

        ivg3 = 1.0 / (g**3)
        sab = sabdt * ivg3

        ! Calculate scattering angle
        if (sab < 0.0016) then
            cospsi = 1.0 + sab * log(r1_local)
        elseif (sab > 6.0) then
            cospsi = 2.0 * r1_local - 1.0
        else
            if (sab < 0.01) then
                aa = 1.0 / sab
            elseif (sab > 3.0) then
                aa = 3.0 * exp(-sab)
            else
                ! Power Law Fit
                aa = 1.07975693*(sab**(-0.98406597))
            end if
            dda = 1.0 / aa
            cospsi = dda * log(exp(-aa) + 2.0 * r1_local * sinh(aa))
        end if
        sinpsi = sqrt(1.0 - cospsi**2)
        beta = twopi * r2_local
        cosbt = cos(beta)
        sinbt = sin(beta)

        hx = gper * cosbt
        hy = -(gy * gx * cosbt + g * gz * sinbt) / gper
        hz = -(gz * gx * cosbt - g * gy * sinbt) / gper

        cospsi = 1.0 - cospsi
        maab = mp / (mp + md)
        mbab = md / (mp + md)

        ! calculate post velocity collisions of each species
        vx_p(ia) = vx_p(ia) - mbab * (gx * cospsi + hx * sinpsi)
        vy_p(ia) = vy_p(ia) - mbab * (gy * cospsi + hy * sinpsi)
        vz_p(ia) = vz_p(ia) - mbab * (gz * cospsi + hz * sinpsi)

        vx_d(ib) = vx_d(ib) + maab * (gx * cospsi + hx * sinpsi)
        vy_d(ib) = vy_d(ib) + maab * (gy * cospsi + hy * sinpsi)
        vz_d(ib) = vz_d(ib) + maab * (gz * cospsi + hz * sinpsi)

        temp_e = 0.5*(vx_p(ia)**2 + vy_p(ia)**2 + vz_p(ia)**2)/EC
        temp_i = 0.5*(vx_d(ib)**2 + vy_d(ib)**2 + vz_d(ib)**2)/EC

        if (ieee_is_nan(temp_e) .or. ieee_is_nan(temp_i)) then
            print *, 'Nan detected in collision subroutine'
            stop 'Simulation stopped due to numerical error'
        endif
    end subroutine collision

    subroutine calculate_temperatures()
        implicit none
        real(8) :: ke_p, ke_d, vxxp, vyyp, vzzp, vxxd, vyyd, vzzd
        real(8) :: txxp,tyyp,tzzp,txxd,tyyd,tzzd
        integer :: i, m, o

        ke_p = 0.0
        ke_d = 0.0
        txxp = 0.0
        tyyp = 0.0
        tzzp = 0.0 
        txxd = 0.0 
        tyyd = 0.0 
        tzzd = 0.0
        vxxp = 0.0
        vyyp = 0.0
        vzzp = 0.0
        vxxd = 0.0
        vyyd = 0.0
        vzzd = 0.0
        m = 0
        o = 0

        !$omp parallel do reduction(+:ke_p,ke_d,vxxp,vyyp,vzzp,vxxd,vyyd,vzzd)
        do i = 1, np
            m=m+np
            o=o+np
            ke_p = ke_p + 0.5 * mp * (vx_p(i)**2 + vy_p(i)**2 + vz_p(i)**2)
            ke_d = ke_d + 0.5 * md * (vx_d(i)**2 + vy_d(i)**2 + vz_d(i)**2)
            txxp = txxp + 0.5 * mp*(vx_p(i)**2)
            tyyp = tyyp + 0.5 * mp*(vy_p(i)**2)
            tzzp = tzzp + 0.5 * mp*(vz_p(i)**2)
            txxd = txxd + 0.5 * md*(vx_d(i)**2)
            tyyd = tyyd + 0.5 * md*(vy_d(i)**2)
            tzzd = tzzd + 0.5 * md*(vz_d(i)**2)
            vxxp = vxxp + vx_p(i)
            vyyp = vyyp + vy_p(i)
            vzzp = vzzp + vz_p(i)
            vxxd = vxxd + vx_d(i)
            vyyd = vyyd + vy_d(i)
            vzzd = vzzd + vz_d(i)           
        end do
        !$omp end parallel do

        if (m/=0 .or. 0/=0) then
            t_p = ke_p *(2.) / (np *EC)
            t_d = ke_d *(2.)/ (np *EC)
            txp = txxp*(2.)/(np*EC)
            typ = tyyp*(2.)/(np*EC)
            tzp = tzzp*(2.)/(np*EC)
            txd = txxd*(2.)/(np*EC)
            tyd = tyyd*(2.)/(np*EC)
            tzd = tzzd*(2.)/(np*EC)
            vxp = vxxp/np
            vyp = vyyp/np
            vzp = vzzp/np
            vxd = vxxd/np
            vyd = vyyd/np
            vzd = vzzd/np
        else
            t_p = 0.0
            t_d = 0.0
            txp = 0.0
            typ = 0.0
            tzp = 0.0
            txd = 0.0
            tyd = 0.0
            tzd = 0.0
            vxp = 0.0
            vyp = 0.0
            vzp = 0.0
            vxd = 0.0
            vyd = 0.0
            vzd = 0.0
            end if 
    end subroutine calculate_temperatures

end module calculations

program main
    use omp_lib
    use constants
    use variables
    use calculations
    implicit none

    real(8) ::  collision_probability

    call alloc_dat

    open(unit=11, file='testcoll_np1000_powerfit3_pd.txt', status='unknown')
    write(11,*) 'm1=', mp , 'm2=' , md
    write(11,*) 'qi(/qe)=', qi/abs(qe)
    write(11,*) 'ne0=', ne,  'ni0=', ni
    write(11,*) 'Te0=', Te, 'Ti0=', Ti
    write(11,*) 'dt=', dt, 'nt=', nt
    write(11,*) 'np=', np
    write(11,*) 'logCou=', logCou
    write(11,*) 'nt T1(eV) T2(eV) tx1 ty1 tz1 tx2 ty2 tz2 vx1 vy1 vz1 vx2 vy2 vz2'

    ! Initialize velocities from Maxwellian distribution
    call initialize_maxwellian(vx_p, vy_p, vz_p, Te, mp, np)
    call initialize_maxwellian(vx_d, vy_d, vz_d, Ti, md, np)

    ! Calculate collision frequency and probability
    collision_probability = 1.0 
    ! Main loop for time iterations
    call random_seed()
    do iter = 1, nt
        !$omp parallel private(ia, ib, r1)
        !$omp do
        do ia = 1, np
            call random_number(r1)
            if (r1 < collision_probability) then
                call random_number(r2)
                ib = int(r2 * np) + 1
                if (ib == ia) ib = mod(ib, np) + 1
                call collision(ia, ib)
            end if
        end do
        !$omp end do
        !$omp end parallel

        call calculate_temperatures()
        write(11,'(I10,2x,14(E15.8,2X))') iter,t_p,t_d,txp,typ,tzp,txd,tyd,tzd,vxp,vyp,vzp,vxd,vyd,vzd
    end do

    close(11)

    call dealloc_dat

    print *, 'Simulation completed successfully.'

end program main


Other people guy suggested me to observe implementation of collision. Here is the picture of my calculation about the scattering angles. The results show me very large angles. This does not correct to physical of ion-ion collision because scattering angle very small due to ion velocity and ion mass. calculate_chi

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Always use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Please understand that this is a programming site and it is important to ask.programming questions. The answerers here will probably not fully understand your physical or mathematical problem.

To start off, a number of your REAL literal constants are in single precision (typically, an IEEE 32-bit floating point entity); while your declarations use REAL(8), which is often an indication of DOUBLE PRECISION, which is typically an IEEE 64-bit entity.  You append a kind type parameter to the constants, i.e., m_e0 = 9.10938356e-31 becomes m_e0 = 9.10938356e-31_8.  It would be better to use a named constant for the kind type parameter, integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0) and then it everywhere that 8 is used,  m_e0 = 9.10938356e-31_dp

Oh my! Are you sure that you want to do if (m /= 0 .or. 0 /= 0) then in calculate_temperature?

What are the purposes of the m and o variables in calculate_temperature?  You are adding np=100000 each time the loop is executed, so at the end you have m=np*np, which oveflows the integer type.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
